# Tools similar to Google Test for C++ unit testing?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

Are there any tools similar to GoogleTest for the purpose of functional testing in C++.
I plan to do them as part of Unit Testing and would like to know of other options available so that I can make an informed choice.

Comment: There are many unit test libraries for C++. [Here](http://www.levelofindirection.com/journal/2010/12/28/unit-testing-in-c-and-objective-c-just-got-easier.html) is my favorite

Comment: Someone increase my reputation pls.. so that I can rate myself which answers were helpful

Comment: The only way to increase your rep is to ask good questions and provide good answers. :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this.
http://gamesfromwithin.com/exploring-the-c-unit-testing-framework-jungle.
And I personally use this, I think it is pretty good.
http://unittest-cpp.sourceforge.net/

Comment: That article is from 2004. It's too out of date to be useful now.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a [look a this](http://gamesfromwithin.com/exploring-the-c-unit-testing-framework-jungle) for a short list of frameworks that you may explore.

Also, here is [why you should use Google Test](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/Primer#Introduction%3a_Why_Google_C++_Testing_Framework?), from the tutorial itself. If find GTest easy to use, test are verbose enough and documentation is clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual studio, it embdeds a Test Unit framework.
I just tried the exemple available on the [MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh270864.aspx), it works pretty well.

Here is the syntax :

```
#include <CppUnitTest.h>
#include "..\MyProjectUnderTest\MyCodeUnderTest.h"
using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;
TEST_CLASS(TestClassName)
{
public:
  TEST_METHOD(TestMethodName)
  {
    // Run a function under test here.
    int actualValue   = MyProject::Multiply(2,3);
    int expectedValue = 6;

    Assert::AreEqual(expectedValue, actualValue, L"Error, the values do not match.", LINE_INFO());
  }
}
```